# Можете привеcтии понятный пример работы команд git "git-http-fetch" "git-http-push" и как через консоль можно воспользоваться "git-http-backend"?

Tags: git

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать с командами git, читал документацию, не понял

> git-http-fetch

> git-http-push

> git-http-backend

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143026/discussion-on-question-by-thanksforwathing--c---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Вы попали под [автоматическую блокировку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) из-за низкого качества вопросов/ответов. Что вы сейчас можете сделать, так это принять ответы на свои вопросы (у вас ни одного принятого ответа), а так же попытаться их улучшить, чтобы вывести в положительный баланс голосов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С начала нужно запустить git-http-backend. Для его работы должны быть установлены переменные окружения GIT_PROJECT_ROOT и нужно передавать в скрипт запуска git-http-backend переменную PATH_INFO.

И только потом, после того как на сервере будет уже работать git-http-backend, получиться работать с командами git-http-push и git-http-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Подключаете remote через http ссылку и делаете fetch/push как обычно...

Comment: Это понятно, что так можно делать. Надо использовать команды в вопросе, а не просто fetch/push через настроенный remote

Comment: Какую задачу этим можно решить?

Comment: @Aleksandr Fetisov кратко написал какую задачу можно решить. Но как это делать, для чего-то же есть эти команды